# Content Editor Web part is not refreshing the html page in IE

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint-2013

I am having a content editor web part in SharePoint 2013 environment. In that have 2 drop downs and a custom grid in which we perform add/edit operations. When we come to the page again it is not showing the updated data in dropdown selection and grid in IE browser but working fine in Chrome. When we use clt+F5 and refresh the page then shows the updated data. It appears that it is showing the data from cache. How can we clear the cache on load so that it shows the updated data. 
Have tried Cache-Control,Pragma,Expires tags but no success:

Please help as occurring in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013, use script editor web part to instead of content editor web part, copy all html code and add into script editor web part, then check if it works.

If it still not work, you can provide the code for further research.

Comment: The issue got resolved by using  cache: false during ajax call which made the data to get refresh.